# Word/phrase to call people who born in the new millennium

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe people who born after 2000. In fact, I want something like **[Millennials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennials)** (rather than teenagers). A not-so-interesting option for that is **[Generation Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Z)**. 
Is there any word/phrase for that?

Comment: Well, the problem is that such terms tend to be either relatively obscure (i.e. one person made it up and no one else is using it) or vaguely defined (i.e. some would say Millenials are only those born >= 2000, others would say the term also includes those born in the '90s). I suppose we need a name for the generation 2005 - 2015, but I just don't think there is such a term as yet. Frankly, they aren't old enough to have a meaningfully defined cultural impact at this point, so it might be a bit premature to name them.

Comment: There won't really be an established term for another 5-10 years, when the first of the cohort is reaching adulthood.  (But it occurs to me that "iPhone generation" is a likely handle, as this is the first group to have lived with smartphones from the beginning.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions from [pewresearch.org](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/):

> - Pew Research Center’s Paul Taylor appeared on Jon Stewart’s “The Daily Show” to discuss his new book, The Next America: Boomers, Millennials, and the Looming Generational Showdown.
> - Suggestions include ***Digital Natives***, ***Generation Like and the Selfie Generation,*** emphasizing this generation’s deep connection to technology; ***the Rainbow Generation***, a nod to their diversity; and ***Homelanders*** or ***the 9/11 Generation***, tributes to how the 9/11 attacks and war on terrorism shaped their early lives.

Jon Stewart made his own suggestions:

> - ***TwoKays or 2K’s***: “Since they are born after 2000 … Y2K?”
> - ***The Conflict Generation***: “They have grown up with two big wars and many little ones. They are witness to the ‘Arab Spring,’ the rise of ethnic factions.”
> - ***Generation i, iGeners, iGens:*** Submitted with the disclaimer “I am not a journalist.”
> - ***@generation or the swipe generation:*** “Thought of that as I watched my son use his iPad.”
> - ***The Tweennials***: “We are in the ‘tweens’ of this century after all.”
> - ***Screeners:*** “My students live and die by the screen.”